# Are there problems that can't be solved efficiently without arrays?

Tags: arrays, haskell, functional-programming, complexity-theory, theory

For someone used to imperative programming, it's sometimes hard to write efficient code in functional languages without using arrays/vectors. However, it seems there's always a smart way of doing it. Sorting, for example, can be done in O(n*log(n)) time both in imperative and declarative programming languages, and the absence of swapping operations is not a real problem.

Consider a functional programming language that has no arrays or any data structure that can access an arbitrary element in constant time. Take a subset of SML or Haskell without arrays, for example.

Of course, every computable problem is solvable by  a program written in such language. But I'm wondering if there is any problem that intrinsically can't be solved efficiently outside the imperative world. By "efficiently", I mean with at most the same time complexity of the best known imperative algorithm to solve the problem.

For example, can matrix multiplication be computed efficiently using only lists in SML or Haskell?

Comment: I'm pretty confident that you can't make a prime sieve without a mutable array as efficiently as with.

Comment: all programming languages are just an abstraction above assembly/machine language

Comment: Are you asking for a problem that requires random access for an optimal solution? How are strings represented in your "array-less, no random access" language?

Comment: @jxh They're linked lists of `Char`s in Haskell, so that would be one possibility.

Comment: @sepp2k: Then the trivial problem is to find the middle of the string in O(1) time.

Comment: @jxh I assume Gabriel was thinking in terms of complete programs with input and output (otherwise the question would be trivial since Gabriel already knows that he can't do random access in O(1) since he specifically excluded that). And if you count input and output, then it would have to be O(n) in both cases since you need to read all the n chars before you can find the middle of them. The question is whether there is any problem where the complete program to solve that problem will be asymptotically slower because you can't do random access in O(1) time.

Comment: @sepp2k: The problem is still trivial. Input: sequence of words, Output: same words in a random order.

Comment: Arrays and random access in themselves are not "unfunctional". Mutability is.

Comment: @sepp2k Note that you can always keep O(1) access to the middle of a list just by taking its "derivative" (i.e. transforming it to a zipper).  You can actually store any number of O(1) "pointers" to the interior of a list this way as long as you take the "derivative" once for each pointer you want to keep track of.  So O(1) access to the middle of any collection does not rule out the use of functional data structures.

Comment: That question is just a more general form of this one, but I think it brings up specific examples to answer it, like the union-find algorithm.

Comment: @DanielFischer a priority queue works well, see: http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: @Wes That has worse time complexity, since the PQ updates aren't `O(1)`. Also, the constant factors are much worse than for mutable arrays.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I would love to see an example of this on haskell for all

Comment: @DiegoNolan It's already in my queue of articles to write. :)